# Globally set region to europe-west1 for a httpsCallable when initializing firebaseApp, instead of us-central1

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Is there a way to globally set the region from which an httpsCallable function is being called. Right now I initialize my app like this:

```js
const app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
app.functions('europe-west1')
```

What is then created is the firebase app object. When console logging the app variable it gives me back an object with the services_ property. In this property there is a function property named europe-west1 as a service. However, when then calling a function that looks like this:

```js
const deleteUserCloudFunction = firebase
    .functions()
    .httpsCallable('deleteUser')
```

another property is created within the functions service, named [DEFAULT] which has the 'us-central1' region specified. How can I change this by default specified region to 'europe-west1'?

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand your question, you should do:

```
var app = firebase.initializeApp(config);
var functions = app.functions('europe-west1');

const deleteUserCloudFunction = firebase
    .functions()
    .httpsCallable('deleteUser')
```

More details in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/locations#http_and_client-callable_functions).

Comment: Hi Renaud, thanks for the response! Yes, I think you understand it correctly. I would expect the code that you have written should lead to the 'deleteUser' function being called in 'europe-west1'. However the 'deleteUserCloudFunction' is still being called in 'us-central1'.

Comment: Is you CF configured to run in this region? See https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#modify-region. You can check that in the CF Dashboard in the Firebase console.

Comment: Hi Renaud, thanks for the quick response! This is what I see for the function in the CF dashboard: https://gyazo.com/9c5748c36f77ab9aece03c094098182d. Does the firebase documentation not mean when declaring `var functions = app.functions('europe-west1');` that the functions variable should be used from that point on? I hope not since that would require a lot more work and seems silly but I fear it =(

Comment: this is what keeps showing in the console: https://gyazo.com/3cd6e072e411837945eaf40711a34aa3. The [DEFAULT] functions service keeps getting initialized with the NA region. Not sure what else I can do.So frustrating...

Comment: This is an interesting part of the documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#initialize_the_client_sdk

Note: To call a function running in any location other than the default us-central1, you must set the appropriate value at initialization. For example, on Android you would initialize with getInstance(FirebaseApp app, String region). Which would lead me to expect that it should be possible at initialization, but no luck -.-